# Our API receive blank message on Trigger Events(envelope signed/completed)

Tags: docusignapi

We have configured our application/listener URL to received envelope signed/completed message. But my application is getting blank message. However I checked DocuSign logs, logs shows docusign application able to connect with our application. I read specification in link https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect
We have developed web API in Microsoft .net , I think, I am doing some mistake in HTTP post method parameter. Please guide how to receive your post message. Our application parameter looks as below

```
public class eSignatureController : ApiController
{
   
    [BasicAuthorizeAttribute]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage ReceiveMessage([FromBody] string 
   signedDocMsg)
    {       
    // Our business logic based parameter
    }
```

We call our API as below, which is take accept parameter

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(ConfigurationHelper.ServerPath + 
@"SampleRequest\msg_5a.xml");

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationHelper.internalWebSiteRootHub);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            string userBase64 = AppSecurity.EncodeToBase64("********");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("authorization", userBase64);

            var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/eSignature", doc.InnerXml);
```

Logs from DocuSign
[image]

Please let me know if any further details required

Comment: Someone from docusign, please answer my question. It seems I need to pass class which wrapper of your response

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign is definitely sending your server application (the "listener") the XML notification as the body of the POST request to your app.

Next step, I recommend that you use your web framework's debugging recommendations to print out the incoming POST request body.

To assure yourself of exactly what the incoming POST looks like, you can use a webhook debugging site such as https://webhook.site

Comment: now able to receive by our web API. Thanks for your team support